# Why is the startup folder in Debian/Ubuntu called "init.d"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Can someone explain the history and the meaning of this name?

Comment: [What is the difference between /etc/init/ and /etc/init.d/?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5039/1059)

Comment: @Gilles: I duckduckwent before asking, to no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It stands for [Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) [Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28disambiguation%29) (two different Wikipedia links).

**init**:

> *init* (short for initialization) is a program for Unix-based computer
>   operating systems that spawns all other processes. It runs as a daemon
>   and typically has PID 1. The boot loader starts the kernel and the
>   kernel starts init. If one were to delete init without a replacement,
>   the system would encounter a kernel panic on the next reboot.
>
> The functionality diverged, in Unix systems such as System III and System
>   V, from the functionality provided by the init in Research Unix and
>   its BSD derivatives. The usage on most Linux distributions is
>   compatible with System V, but some distributions, such as Arch, use a
>   BSD-style and others, such as Gentoo, have their own customized
>   version.

**.d:**

> *.d*, a common pathname component suffix for a directory for a program
>   or subsystem on POSIX and POSIX-like systems; for example
>   "/etc/init.d" would be a directory which contains files associated
>   with the init program.

Comment: See also: [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html), section 9.3.1, and [init(8)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?init+8)